# Laravel Passport - Passing access token to requests

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

I'm working with Laravel Passport for the first time. I'm building an API that will be consumed by a mobile application.

For the authentication, this is what i'm doing:

```
public function login(Request $request)
{ 
    $loginData = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required',
    ]);

    if( $loginData->fails() )
    {
        return response()->json(['error' => $loginData->errors()], 401);
    }

    if( Auth::attempt(['email' => request('email'), 'password' => request('password')]) )
    { 
        $data = [
            'grant_type' => 'password',
            'client_id' => $this->client->id,
            'client_secret' => $this->client->secret,
            'username' => $request->email,
            'password' => $request->password,
            'scope' => '',
        ];

        $request = Request::create('/oauth/token', 'POST', $data);
        return app()->handle($request);
    } 
    else
    { 
        return response()->json(['error' => 'Invalid credentials'], 401); 
    } 
}
```

Successful login returns the access token as such:

```
{
"token_type": "Bearer",
"expires_in": 31622400,
"access_token": "access_token",
"refresh_token": "refresh_token"
}
```

Now the aim is to use this access token by passing it to the header of all routes that need authentication.

For example in my `routes/api.php` file, i have this route:

```
Route::post('/login', 'API\AuthController@login');
Route::apiResource('/tasks', 'API\TaskController')->middleware('auth:api');
```

In my `TaskController`, all the methods in it need to be passed a header that contains the access token so as to authenticate the request. This is where my question is. I can't seem to find a resource so far that explains how to do this. So in every request i need to pass something like this to the header of the request:

```
Accept: application/json
Authorization: Bearer access_token
```

This is my `TaskController` `index` method. How do i pass the access token in here?

```
public function index()
{
    //how do i capture the access token in here so that i can pass it to the request header?
    return TaskResource::collection(auth()->user()->tasks()->latest()->paginate(4));
}
```

Is there a default Passport method that can be used to pass the access token to required requests or how can it be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
public function index(Request $request)
{
       $bearerToken = $request->header('Authorization'); // will return "Bearer access_token" string
}
```

Then you will need to get `access_token` from `"Bearer access_token"` string.
If you need `access_token` to retrieve user, you can use `$user = $request->user()` to get user.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your input. What you propose here requires the access token to be already be in the header. My question is, after login and creating the access token, how can i use it across all requests that require authentication. How do i actually pass the access token in any authenticated request to my header?

Comment: What language do you use in your mobile app?

Comment: for example, you are using `http://example.com/api/tasks` endpoint and it is protected with access token

Comment: You make request with header with key `Authorization` and value `Bearer $accesstoken` (like `Bearer eyj3...`)

Comment: its an android app. So will be sending a json payload to be consumed by the android. now in this payload, this is where i'll pass the access token together with the response payload and this header is what will be used to authenticate the request. Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: example for get method maybe something like this `HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet('http://example.com/api/tasks');
            httpGet .setHeader("Authorization", Bearer access_token");`

Comment: You got your access token from laravel app. 1. You create request object in android. 2. Set header for this request with key `Authorization` and value `Bearer "access_token"`

Comment: now this is the part i'm pulling hair. after i generate the access token after the user logins, how do i pass this access token to all the requests that require authentication ? i.e. use the access token in the header of the response i'm sending via the endpoint that will be used by the mobile app

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193328/discussion-between-some-dev-and-suo).

Comment: you are a life save.

Comment: @ahmednawazbutt glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

using **$request->bearerToken();** method you can get the request token.

```
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
           echo $request->bearerToken();
    }
```